# How edit the JTextArea in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea

I'm developing a application with `Swing` . I have a `JTable`. In my `JTable` I'm adding a `JTextArea` , but the `JTextArea` can't be edited. my problem in `DefaultCellEditor`   ,
My code:

```
import com.sun.java.accessibility.util.AWTEventMonitor;
import com.sun.rowset.internal.InsertRow;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.EventObject;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.CellEditor;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneUI;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.text.TableView;

/**
 *
 * @author brahim
 */
public class ExpertInterface1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public JFrame jframe ; 
    public int sourisx1 ;
    public int sourisy1 ;
    public int sourisx2 ;
    public int sourisy2 ;
    public boolean  souris ; 
    /**
     * Creates new form InterfaceMain
     */
    public ExpertInterface1() {
    jframe=this;
        setUndecorated(true);
    setBackground(new Color(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.5f));

    souris =true; 
    mouse(); 

    show();

    initComponents();

    this.jframe.setBackground(new Color(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.8f));

  this.jPanel3.setBackground(new Color(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
  this.jPanel1.setBackground(new Color(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
  this.jPanel4.setBackground(new Color(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
  this.jPanel2.setBackground(new Color(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
  this.jPanel5.setBackground(new Color(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));

  table();  
    }
    BrmTableModel Brmtablemodel ;
    DefaultTableCellRenderer Brmcellrender ;
    DefaultCellEditor Brmcelleditor ;

    void table()
    { 
          /*sauvgarder les donnees */
       Brmtablemodel = new BrmTableModel();
       /*affichage */

       Brmcellrender= new BrmEditTextAfficher();

        jTable1.getColumn("").setMaxWidth(30);
        jTable1.getColumn("").setMinWidth(30);
        jTable1.setRowHeight(80);
        jTable1.setModel(Brmtablemodel);

        //jTable1.getColumn(1).setCellEditor(Brmcelleditor);
       //jTable1.getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(Brmcellrender);
        jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, Brmcellrender);
        jTable1.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, Brmcelleditor);
    jTable1.getColumn("B").setCellEditor( Brmcelleditor);

    }





    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(1, 50, 5, 5));

        jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 220, 255), 2));

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new java.awt.Color(22, 227, 246)));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 47, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new java.awt.Color(22, 227, 246)));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 126, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jPanel4.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new java.awt.Color(22, 227, 246)));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
        jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
        jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 32, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jPanel5.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new java.awt.Color(22, 227, 246)));

        jTable1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED, new java.awt.Color(108, 254, 225), new java.awt.Color(108, 254, 225), java.awt.Color.blue, java.awt.Color.blue));
        jTable1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("TlwgMono", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "", "Les symptômes", "la maladie"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel5Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel5);
        jPanel5.setLayout(jPanel5Layout);
        jPanel5Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 730, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel5Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(136, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(157, 157, 157)
                        .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jSeparator1))))
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(639, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addComponent(jPanel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(13, 13, 13)
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(672, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ExpertInterface1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ExpertInterface1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ExpertInterface1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ExpertInterface1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ExpertInterface1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

        void mouse(){

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            int thisX = jframe.getLocation().x;
            int thisY = jframe.getLocation().y;

            // Determine how much the mouse moved since the initial click
            int xMoved = (thisX + e.getX()) - (thisX + sourisx1);
            int yMoved = (thisY + e.getY()) - (thisY + sourisy1);

            // Move window to this position
            int X = thisX + xMoved;
            int Y = thisY + yMoved;
            jframe.setLocation(X, Y);



        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

           /*   if(e.getButton()==e.MOUSE_EXITED)
              {
             //  jframe.setLocation(jframe.getX()+1, jframe.getY() +1);
              }
    */    
    }

    });

            addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

              sourisx1=e.getX();
              sourisy1=e.getY();

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration                   





class BrmTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

     Object[] columns = {"","Les Symptones","La maladie"};
     Object [][] rows={{"z","z","z"}};


        public void setColumns(Object[] columns) {

            this.columns = columns;
        }




    public BrmTableModel()
    {
        super();
    }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() { 
        return rows.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return rows[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

            if(columnIndex==1)

         super.setValueAt(aValue, rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return super.isCellEditable(rowIndex, columnIndex); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }



}





class BrmEditTextAfficher extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
        public BrmEditTextAfficher() {
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

          if(column == 1 )
          {  
              //GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(1, 1);
              //JPanel panel = new JPanel(gl);
             //panel.add(new ());
            //  return (new  ChaqueMaladieExpert()) ;
             JTextArea xe = new JTextArea() ;
             xe.setEditable(true);
              return (xe );
          }
              else
              return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        }


}



class BrmEditTextEdit extends DefaultCellEditor {

        public BrmEditTextEdit(JTextField textField) {

            super(textField);

        }

   public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                   boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();

        textarea.setEditable(true);

        return textarea;
   }



    }





}
```

how to resolve my problem  ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590017/display-popup-jframe-under-jtable-cell/20590066#20590066 for an example of using a JTextArea as an editor.

Comment: I have a problem in my DefaultCellEditor

Comment: which is why I pointed you to an example that works.

Comment: Also seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513). To avoid GUI editor hassles, use the approach suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the 'editable' box in the properties menu of the `JTextArea`
[image: Image of properties menu in NetBeans GUI builder]
Edit: To change this in the source code, place this line after where your `JTextArea` is created:

```
textarea.setEditable(true);
```

Comment: @MohaMed Edited that in.

Comment: It remained the same problem

Comment: Your code is also a little weird. You have 10 compilation warnings, and it seems the class `BrmEditTextEdit` (The only one which uses a `JTextArea`) is never used.

Comment: and what is the solution  ?

Comment: Looking at your code, the problem seems to be that you never actually use a `JTextArea` at all.

Comment: what is my problém ?